# How to Confirm Phone Number in ASP Identity 2

Tags: asp.net-identity

In the new Identity 2, if I want to confirm user email, I can call UserManager.ConfirmEmail(userId, token). However I can't find how to confirm Phone number. Or am I getting the whole idea wrong?

Comment: this post helped me .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956824/how-to-confirm-a-phone-number-in-asp-net-core-1-1mvc?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 13):

Here is how I solved it:

1. I simply fetched the user using `UserManager.FindByName()`.
2. I set the fetched user's `PhoneConfirmed` to `true`.
3. I call `UserManager.UpdateAsync()` and pass in the updated user.

Just one additional method from Microsoft would have saved these round trips!

Comment: This is not not a good method .. how you are going to verify that phone confirmation token is correct

Comment: With _userManager.VerifyChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(user, token, newNumber);

Answer (score 3):

The function `ChangePhoneNumberAsync(TUser user, string phoneNumber, string token)` is updating the phone number confirm field to be true