# How to confirm a phone number in ASP.Net Core 1.1MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I cannot figure out how to do a phone number confirmation in asp.net core 1.1

Identity service configuration contains explicit options to require confirmed email and/or phone number.

It can be done the following way:

```
services
    .AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = true;
     });
```

The validation of the email is quite straight forward as the UserManager contains explicit token generator and its validator:

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
```

The generated token can be validated the following way:

```
var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
```

The above line will switch the user.EmailConfirmed flag to true if the token is valid.

Now the problem is that I don't see a similar method to generate a phone validation token and its equivalent method to validate it (which in turn should switch the user.PhoneNumberConfirmed flag to true if successful).

User manager contains however few methods to do a user phone change:

```
_userManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync();
```

and

```
_userManager.VerifyChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync();
```

But it seems these methods don't switch the user.PhoneNumberConfirmed flag.

Am I missing something? What would be the correct way to confirm the user phone number (in other words to set user.PhoneNumberConfirmed to true) ?

Comment: Phone confirmation requires an external service like twilio to do the confirmation by sending sms messages. I have implemented that stuff in my project here https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe

Comment: @JoeAudette Well, I'm not interested in how to deliver a confirmation code but how to validate it correctly. Can you point me please where you do that ?

Comment: If you see [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/1.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserManager.cs#L1518), the only place that sets PhoneNumberConfirmed to true is in `ChangePhoneNumberAsync(TUser user, string phoneNumber, string token)`

Comment: @tmg Hmmm, I see. it doesn't feel symmetric as it is for email confirmation where I don't have to set the email again (and for which there is also a similar method ChangeEmailAsync). I would have expected something like ConfirmPḧoneNumberAsync(TUser user, string token).

Comment: you can see code sample that may shed light for you in my [managecontroller](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Core.Web.Mvc/Controllers/ManageController.cs)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thanks to @tmg for pointing me to the source code.

According to it, the right way is indeed to use `GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync` in order to generate a token and `ChangePhoneNumberAsync` to validate it (which in turn sets `PhoneNumberConfirmed` to true if validation succeeds):

```
var token = await _userManager
    .GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(user, user.PhoneNumber);

var result = await _userManager
    .ChangePhoneNumberAsync(user, user.PhoneNumber, token);
```

**Remark**: in ASP.NET Core 2.0.0, unfortunately, there is a bug (regression) and `GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync` does not generate an SMS-friendly token anymore and is currently useless:

[GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync is not generating an SMS-friendly token in ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1388)

Comment: OMG this bug. Been messing with me.

Comment: this wasted my 2 hours :(

Comment: appears it's been fixed in .net core 3.0

Comment: It takes me `InvalidToken` error on `ChangePhoneNumberAsync `